# How to change datepicker set the first date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Question: where can I place the following code:

```js
// Getter 
var defaultDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );

// Setter 
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +7 );
```

I have placed it after tag but it doesn't work. I would like to set the first date 7 days from today.

I'm trying to set the code in a code snippet but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setDate` option after initialize your `datepicker` to set the desire date (For example: 7 days from today).

Example:

```js
$(".selector").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
  // other options goes here
});
$(".selector").datepicker("setDate", "7");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css ">


<input class='selector' type='text' />
```